# Micro service: how to share information about an initial request across services?

Tags: microservices, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to dev a project using the micro service architecture.
Basically the app will allow a user to run a machine learning algorithm on a choosen set of data.
Informations about the data will be an input of an interface.
For now I identified 3 services:

- The interface, S1.
- A service that will just source the data the user asked for, S2.
- A service that will run the algorithm on the data, S3.

I chose to make these services communicate through a PubSub, as it involves long running jobs.

For now, here is what it looks like:

https://ibb.co/RYj321G

When a request is made on the interface (S1), I push a message to a specific PubSub topic. It contains informations about the data to be used. This topic is only consumed by the S2 service.
S2 sources the data. Now I would like the ML service to start running a job.
The thing is, S3 needs to know S2 sources the data but it also needs informations contained by the message S2 consumed. What is the way to do it ?

- S2 pushes a new message to message to PubSub containing the content of the initial message, + something indicating the job is done ?
- S3 also consumes the initial message from S1 but I make sure it only runs when it pulls a message from S2 saying the data is ready ?

Comment: Please post images here instead of external site.

Answer (score 0):

There are many valid approaches:

1. If the data that S1 *pushes* is needed by both S2 and S3 the have both listen on the topic.  When S2 *pushes* data to S3 it now have all the information it needs and it can process the request.  This would be in the spirit of PubSub where the sender doesn't worry about you needs to consume the data.  S1 only pushes the data once.
2. S1 *pushes* data to only S2. S2 then *pushes* both the data from S1 and S2 to S3.  S2 is doing extra work to relay data.
3. S1 sends data to only S2. S2 sends only it's data to S3.  S3 then *pulls* whatever data it needs from S1 (i.e. sends a message to S1 asking for it, and S1 then sends it again).  The main benefit of 3 is that S3 controls when it's ready to process the request (i.e. flow control).

Instead of sending data around (services have private storage) you can also send an identifier, and the services then go and retrieve the data when they need it (data lake).